# gltail “Missing gem net-ssh”

Tags: troubleshooting, rubygems

I'm attempting to get gltail set up on my local system to monitor logs remotely.

I've got all the dependencies installed, but when I go to run gltail ...

```
./gl_tail configfile ../config.yaml
```

I get this output:

```
Missing gem net-ssh.
Ubuntu:
  sudo gem install -y net-ssh -r
```

.. which I've done a number of times. Here is the output:

```
dev@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Fudge-gltail-e5b252d/bin$ sudo gem install net-ssh
Successfully installed net-ssh-2.0.15
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-2.0.15...
Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-2.0.15...
```

But when I go to run it again, I get the same missing gem net-ssh error.

```
dev@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Fudge-gltail-e5b252d/bin$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
dev@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Fudge-gltail-e5b252d/bin$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

Why isn't net-ssh being seen as properly installed?

Answer (score 1):

for gltail please use

```
gem install -y net-ssh -v 1.1.4
```

Comment: Yeah, for me it only worked using the gem install. If I remember correctly there was a dependency that was not covered by the ubuntu package.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you may get:

ERROR:  could not find gem net-ssh locally or in a repository

So, browse to:

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=274

And download "net-ssh-1.1.4.gem."

cd into download directory, and type:

sudo gem install -y net-ssh -v 1.1.4

sudo gem install gltail